# For each cell in range, total next column cell

Tags: excel, vba

For each "farm" in column A; sum the values from column C (Count) for "apple-1" and "apple-2" in column B.

Looping thru searching and adding. No errors.  Math is occurring from the wrong cells.

Data

[Data table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3MyWx.png)

```
Sub find_2()

Dim apple_1 As Long, apple_2 As Long
Dim j As Integer
Dim total_aps As Long

Dim name As Range
Dim myrange As Range

last_row = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row

Set myrange = Range("A2:A17" & last_row)

Sheets("Sheet1").Activate

With ActiveSheet

    For j = 16 To last_row
        For Each name In myrange
              If .Cells(j, 2).Value = ("apple-1") Then
                apple_1 = Sheet1.Cells(j, 3).Value
              End If
              If .Cells(j, 2).Value = ("apple-2") Then
                apple_2 = Sheet1.Cells(j, 3).Value
              End If

    total_aps = apple_1 + apple_2 

        .Cells(j, 6).Value = total_aps

    Next

    Next j

End With

End Sub

=======================================================================


Expected/Wanted results

Farm       Total Count

farm-01    300

farm-02    30

farm-03    3

farm-04    3000
```

Actual results  (see Totals Count)
[Actual results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YmBkx.png)

Comment: Why don't you just use a pivot table?

Comment: Thank you SJR.  But, I would like to figure out how to create the "total" summary without using a pivot table.